# Android ParseFile array not loading images

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have an array of ParseObjects that are being displayed in a list view. Three text views are loaded into my custom cell, and then there's an image in a ParseFile that should also be loaded. The code I have gets the first cell to load correctly, but in every other cell the image doesn't load. Here's my code:

```
        this.origImage = (ParseFile) posts.get(position).get("image");
        try {
            Log.d("MyMessage", "Gonna convert image");
            this.imageData = this.origImage.getData();
            this.options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            this.options.inDither = true;
            this.options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            this.options.inSampleSize = 8;
            this.notConvertedYet = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.imageData, 0, this.imageData.length, this.options);
            if (this.notConvertedYet != null)
                this.myBitmap = rotateImage(90, this.notConvertedYet);
            else
                this.myBitmap = this.notConvertedYet;
            mHolder.picImageView.setImageBitmap(this.myBitmap);
            Log.d("MyMessage", "Converted image");

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What is happening that's messing it up?

Comment: In what function are you calling this?

Comment: My custom array adapter, in the getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

when its bound to a list adapter, what does the

```
posts.get(position).get("image");
```

do actually? Is the parse SDK calling a series of AsyncTasks for the network Http GET on the actual URL in parse's file CDN?

You may have to find out more about what its doing because , as is, it may not be very efficient as used by the Adapter.getView()...

Any image loader framework like Volley, like Universal Image Loader, like AQuery will work like an api where you make a call providing the ImageView and the CDN URL for the image as parms.  The framework will handle multithreading, pooled Parse.com connections , memCache and fileCache for all images. When using parse to store bitmaps in the file CDN you can still use any of the image loading frameworks.

AQuery sample in an adapter...

```
ImageView thumbnail=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); // thumb image
mAquery.id(thumbnail).width(110).image($thumbUrl_CDN,
        true, true, 0, R.drawable.default_video, null, 0, mAspectRatio);
```

Your code looks ok.. maybe the reason all the imageViews are black is that the adapter did not have time to get the files loaded across the network and the loop  statement did not block the UI thread??

Comment: posts is the name of an array of ParseObjects from my activity. It's getting the ParseObject that needs to be displayed in the cell and then getting the ParseFile stored in the key "image". I know it's getting the ParseObjects ok because the other variables stored in those ParseObjects are being loaded correctly.